# Filter Checklist, Copy/Paste Range to another Sheet (Location Based on Word Match), Insert New Rows as Needed, initiate on Button Click, Reset Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm working in Google Sheets using Apps Script, on a spreadsheet that has 4 tabs. Names are: "Testing Plan","Blue Test Catalog", "Red Test Catalog", "Green Test Catalog".

On the Catalog Tabs, I want the Leads to go in, and click all the checkboxes for all the tests that need to be completed. So Blue Lead reviews and assigns all the Blue Tests from the Blue Test Catalog, and Red/Green Leads do the same. Once each person has checked all their boxes, they click a button on their sheet "Add To Plan".

All of the checked boxes and their rows from their tab are then copied over to the Testing Plan tab, under the corresponding Test Section (Blue Tests, Red Tests, Green Tests). So I have one neat doc that lists all the tests in one place by their category.

The trick is, I need the code to be able to insert enough blank rows under each section to accommodate the list of items being copied over from each section.

I then want to be able to clear the doc and "reset it" back to how it looks now, as needed (via button click).

I'm not good at coding - its not a normal part of my job. But I've been able to piece some things together over the years based on my google searching and this website, so I thought I'd reach out for help. I unfortunately don't even have any sample code to work off of. I've spent 2 full days attempting this and keep deleting. I've managed to at least write a script to copy and paste a range based on whichever button/sheet location I'm at, but it copies to the bottom of the page. I can't figure out how to do a list filter based on checkbox value being TRUE, and then only copy and paste those values. And then I'll need to figure out how to have the code search and match 'Blue Tests' from the Blue Test Catalog tab with the word 'Blue Tests' on the Test Planning Tab and paste 4 rows down from that, inserting new rows as needed to ensure no overwriting.

Any help would be appreciated. [Sample Sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aW5aQrHInwge2XrDF6to0_9JCUm3rppPJMxV_dSyKIQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: This is a very common question you should be able to find several scripts like this on SO and other locations.  Do you own research on this.

Comment: Thanks Cooper - I've been doing research on this and attempting it on my own for 2 days. Unfortunately I am not a skilled coder so I might not be looking in the right areas or using the right keywords. Hoping someone is able to help me in the community.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not doing it with this simpler way

```
={"Blue test","","","","";query('Blue Test Catalog'!A3:AG,"select B,K,N,Q,X where A=true",1);
"","","","","";
"Red test","","","","";query('Red Test Catalog'!A3:AG,"select B,K,N,Q,X where A=true",1);
"","","","","";
"Green test","","","","";query('Green Test Catalog'!A3:AG,"select B,K,N,Q,X where A=true",1)}
```

I add some conditonal formatting

[image]

something possible to do to split the formula in 5 packages

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mike - I have a question though. The formatting I have is important aesthetically. Is there any way to replace the "select B,K,N,Q,X " portion with a range instead? I want to copy and paste the exact range which is already formatted exactly how it should copy over. Would you wrap the query in an array to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no simple way with merged cells, even by script.

Comment: take a look at the second version

Comment: all formulas are in row#9 in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pIsMDK0yVWgYhgr7oiui7-AwG1f21csicL-_Obl6lcw/copy

Comment: Thank you Mike! I ended up implementing your solution and just protecting the formula cells so no one messes with it. Appreciate the help here.